# linker error in c

Tags: c, linker

how can i resolve a linker error in c?

this is the error message:

undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetRGBStroke`

Comment: add `-lharu` to your compiler's command?

Comment: i already downloaded a haru library and extract it and paste all the header of libharu in the 'include' directory (folder) to my compiler (dev-c++). is it right to do??

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an external library, you have to tell the linker that it should be included. It has no means of automagically finding out what you're using there.

Using `gcc` you can do this by compiling the program with `-l`*library*.

Comment: i already downloaded a haru library and extract it and paste all the header of libharu in the 'include' directory (folder) to my compiler (dev-c++). is it right to do??

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you're trying to use a routine from the libharu PDF library, and it seems you're not linking against this library.

How exactly you would resolve this depends on the toolchain you're using -- under gcc, you would have to add a `-lharu` option or similar to the linker options.

Comment: i already downloaded a haru library and extract it and paste all the header of libharu in the 'include' directory (folder) to my compiler (dev-c++). is it right to do??

Comment: @mark: Probably not. You will also need to compile the library sources and place the resulting library in a place where the linker can find it. Most libraries come with instructions on how to do this -- I would expect that this also applies to libharu.

Comment: @mark: libharu should come with instructions on how to compile it. I've never used it myself -- sorry...